# Merge results from multiple Application.GetOpenFilename statements

Tags: excel, vba

My script gets a list of filenames using Application.GetOpenFilename and assigns them to a variant-declared variable (varList1). So far, the script works fine.

I want to call Application.GetOpenFilename again to get a second list of filenames (varList2).

How do I append varList2 to varList1 or how do I combine them both to a third variable (varList)? This would be much easier to handle than editing the script to loop through a second list of filenames.

```
Dim varList1, varList2, varList As Variant
Dim lReturn As Long
Dim itm as Object

lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(sBasePath & "\" & lYear & "\")
varList1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(sBasePath & "\" & lYear+1 & "\")
varList2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

varList = ?

or

(This give an "object required" error)
For each itm in varList2
   varList1.Add(itm)
next itm
```

Comment: You need to be using an array in order to use an iterator (`for each`). Your code is rather confusing, anyway. It's unclear why you have `varList1`, `varList2 and `varList` at all. A single array with 2 elements would contain both directory names, and you could assign them directly to the array element without any need to *add them* or iterate at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're selecting multiple files, the variant is an array. This code creates a 3rd array to store all the files.

```
Sub GetFiles()
    Dim varList1, varList2, varList As Variant
    Dim lReturn As Long
    Dim itm As Variant
    
    Dim FileList() As String  ' all files
    
    lReturn = SetCurrentDirectory(sBasePath & "\" & lYear & "\")
    varList1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
    lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(sBasePath & "\" & lYear + 1 & "\")
    varList2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If IsArray(varList1) Then  '<~~ If user selects multiple file
        ReDim Preserve FileList(UBound(varList1) - 1) ' expand main array
        For i = LBound(varList1) To UBound(varList1)  ' copy files
            FileList(i - 1) = varList1(i)
        Next i
    Else                       ' <~~ If user selects single file
        FileList(0) = varList1
    End If
    
    curcnt = UBound(FileList)  ' from first list
    
    If IsArray(varList2) Then  '<~~ If user selects multiple file
        ReDim Preserve FileList(UBound(FileList) + UBound(varList2))  ' expand main array
        For i = LBound(varList2) To UBound(varList2)  ' add new files
            FileList(i + curcnt) = varList2(i)
        Next i
    Else                       '<~~ If user selects single file
        FileList(1 + curcnt) = varList2
    End If
        
    For Each itm In FileList
       MsgBox itm
    Next itm
End Sub
```